# Saying something and doing the opposite

Tags: word-choice

What do you call someone who says that they are not doing something then turn around and do exactly what they say they would not do.

Comment: It would be helpful to give an example.  The word you need would be very different if the statement was "I won't fall." vs. "I won't push you."

Answer (score 2):

Such a person is commonly referred to as a "**hypocrite**".

From Merriam-Webster:

> 1. a person who puts on a false appearance of virtue or religion
> 2. **a person who acts in contradiction to his or her stated beliefs or feelings**